# Kafka: Single Topic vs Multiple Topics

Tags: java, events, apache-kafka

I am relatively new to Kafka/Event-Based architectures and need your help.

I have a service where clients can create jobs via REST to be processed asynchronously.
Once the job is complete, the client which placed the job needs to be asynchronously informed of the process state (e.g. done, canceled, expired)

- no ordering guarantees needed
- about 1 million jobs per day
- two clients placing ~400k jobs, most clients placing <1000 jobs per day
- ~20 clients placing jobs
- each client is responsible for a specific job-type
- message format is the same for all clients ({"id": , "state": })

How should this be implemented?

**One Large Topic:**

the processor-service publishes all JobEvents into a single kafka topic

- Simple
- Ready if a consumer needs to react to JobEvents of more than one job-type
- Most clients are not interested in 99% of the events, is this a problem?

**Multiple Topics:**

clients can specify via REST the topic name on which they expect the JobEvent message.

- More complex
- Different job-types are loosely coupled
- Clients get only the events in which they are interested in

I am leaning more to "multiple topics".
Mostly because each consumer only gets the events in which it is interested in.

Are there some additional advantages/disadvantages of the different approaches?
What are your opinions on this?